# Why is nothing returned?

Tags: variables, post, model-view-controller

I'm battling to see why nothing comes back from the following....

[image]

When I utilise the above, it returns nothing....

[image]

I have tried explicitly declaring the variable but `tohdn` will not pass it's contents to `toList`. I have even tried

`string toHdnString = tohdn;`

and `toHdnString` wont keep or take the variable. There is no error message.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really clear from the screen shots what you're trying to describe.  What do you mean by "won't keep or take the variable"?  What, specifically, is happening?

Comment: The POST variable 'tohdn' returns a string of id's (eg: "1,2,3") after pushing 'Send' on my page. The 'GetMultipleSelect' takes these, gets the user id and returns this as a list. 'GetMultipleSelect' definitely returns something but the variable it returns to, toList, just isn't holding it and is empty.

Comment: I don't see how that's indicated in the screen shots.  If a method returns a value and that return value is assigned to a variable, it *will* be stored in that variable.